# Spring Boot Repository date in char column

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with a legacy system where the date is stored in a char(10) column in format dd.MM.yyyy. Is it possible to convert between String and LocalDate/Date transparently to write Queries like

```
Iterable<User> findByRegistrationDateBefore(LocalDate deadline)
```

I tried to use a custom @Query with JPQL but I always use database dependent functions which is not fine.

```
@Query("select u from User u where DATE(u.registrationDate) < DATE(:deadline)")
Iterable<User> customFind(@Param("deadline") LocalDate deadline);
```

This should work with MySQL but since I use H2 it won't work on both. Is there a way/workaround to archive this? I want to search by date in the database and can't load all entries and search in java.

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.example.datecharcolumn.DateFormatConverter;

import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@ToString
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false, precision = 5)
    private Integer userId;

    @Convert(converter = DateFormatConverter.class)
    @Column(name ="REGDAT", nullable = false, length = 10, columnDefinition = "char(10)")
    private Date registrationDate;
}
```

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {
    Iterable<User> findByRegistrationDateAfter(Date d);
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DateCharcolumnApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DateCharcolumnApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Converter
public class DateFormatConverter implements AttributeConverter<Date, String> {

    private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Date attribute) {
        final String format = simpleDateFormat.format(attribute);
        return format;
    }

    @Override
    public Date convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        try {
            Date parse = simpleDateFormat.parse(dbData);
            return parse;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

My idea was that JPQL is smart enough to support the expression of date functions and converts them to the corresponding database dialect (or there is a way to make it smart). But currently (on h2) it just binds to VARCHAR and does a string compare (assuming this is no special H2 grammar that works with dates):

```
select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.regdat as regdat2_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.regdat>?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.regdat as regdat2_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.regdat>?
2020-05-11 17:00:38.877 TRACE 4288 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [20.07.2020]
```

Comment: To compare you need to use Date db function becasue query run on db or fetch all data then compare in app

Answer (score 0):

> My idea was that JPQL is smart enough to support the expression of date functions and converts them to the corresponding database dialect

JPA can't do miracles.
There is no well defined or "obvious" way to translate a `Date` into a `VARCHAR`.
Many databases simply define one to ease specifications of dates but that is dependent on the database and at least in some cases on the configuration and the current date and therefore not a good fit for JPA to use.

The proper way to store `Date` instances in a database is to use a `DATE` type in you database. Then also the conversion will happen. Of course you still have to make sure that the timezones are all handled properly.

If you want to stick with `VARCHAR` you can use a [SpEL expression](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) in your annotated query to do the conversion.

You didn't ask about it, but since you use H2 ans MySQL I assume you use H2 for testing. 
Don't do that.
Use Testcontainers instead.
There are subtle differences between different database engines and you want to test with the same database you use for production.